# requestWindowFeature

Tags: java, android

Почему свойство:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

скидывается после того, как свернуть в трей,развернуть приложение.

Часть кода где это используется

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.view);
```

Попытка использовать  `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` после `setContentView`, например в onResume, приводит к падению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ отсюда [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26383795/7414262)

---

В onResume нужно добавить:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
     | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```